# Zipkin tracing not working for docker-compose and Dapr

Tags: docker-compose, zipkin, dapr

Traces that should have been sent by dapr runtime to zipkin server somehow fails to reach it.

The situation is the following:

I'm using Docker Desktop on my Windows PC. I have downloaded the sample from dapr repository (https://github.com/dapr/samples/tree/master/hello-docker-compose) which runs perfectly out of the box with *docker-compose up*.

Then I've added Zipkin support as per dapr documentation:

1. added this service in the bottom of docker-compose.yml

```yaml
  zipkin:
    image: "openzipkin/zipkin"
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
    networks:
      - hello-dapr
```

2. added config.yaml in *components* folder

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: daprsystem
spec:
  mtls:
    enabled: false
  tracing:
    enabled: true
    exporterType: zipkin
    samplingRate: "1"
    expandParams: true
    includeBody: true
    zipkin:
      endpointAddress: "http://zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans"
```

When application runs, it should send traces to the server, but nothing is found in zipkin UI and logs.

Strange thing start to appear in the logs from *nodeapp-dapr_1* service: **error while reading spiffe id from client cert**

```
pythonapp-dapr_1  | time="2021-03-15T19:14:17.9654602Z" level=debug msg="found mDNS IPv4 address in cache: 172.19.0.7:34549" app_id=pythonapp instance=ce32220407e2 scope=dapr.contrib type=log ver=edge
nodeapp-dapr_1    | time="2021-03-15T19:14:17.9661792Z" level=debug msg="error while reading spiffe id from client cert: unable to retrieve peer auth info. applying default global policy action" app_id=nodeapp instance=773c486b5aac scope=dapr.runtime.grpc.api type=log ver=edge
nodeapp_1         | Got a new order! Order ID: 947
nodeapp_1         | Successfully persisted state.
```

Additional info - current dapr version used is 1.0.1. I made sure that security (mtls) is disabled in config file.

Answer (score 4):

Configuration file is supposed to be in different folder then `components`.

1. Create new folder e.g. `dapr` next to the `components` folder.
2. Move `components` folder into newly created `dapr` folder.
3. Then create `config.yaml` in `dapr` folder.
4. Update docker-compose accordingly.

#### docker-compose

```yaml
services:
  nodeapp-dapr:
    image: "daprio/daprd:edge"
    command: ["./daprd",
     "-app-id", "nodeapp",
     "-app-port", "3000",
     "-placement-host-address", "placement:50006",
     "-dapr-grpc-port", "50002",
     "-components-path", "/dapr/components",
     "-config", "/dapr/config.yaml"]
    volumes:
      - "./dapr/components/:/dapr"
    depends_on:
      - nodeapp
    network_mode: "service:nodeapp"
```

#### config.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: daprConfig
spec:
  mtls:
    enabled: false
  tracing:
    enabled: true
    samplingRate: "1"
    expandParams: true
    includeBody: true
    zipkin:
      endpointAddress: http://host.docker.internal:9411/api/v2/spans
```

> I had issue with `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` in URL which I resolved using  `host.docker.internal` as hostname.

PS: Don't forget to kill all `*-dapr_1` containers so it can load new configuration.

Comment: Thanks! But had to modify mounting of volume into this ->
    volumes:
      - "./dapr/:/dapr"